# Problem of article

Tags: articles

> This pure __ environment makes an effect on __ walker's health and mind, when __ man enjoys __ beauties and solemnity of __ nature in __ morning.

**What would be the articles in the gaps?**

**My assumption:**
  ×  ,  a  ,  the ,  the ,  × ,  the.

Therefore:

> This pure environment makes an effect on **the** walker's health and mind, when **a** man enjoys **the** beauties and solemnity of nature in **the** morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I think is right as for articles in this sentence:

> This pure **(-)** environment makes an effect on **the** walker's health and mind, when **(-)** man (I would say *one* in this case) enjoys **the** beauties and solemnity of **(-)** nature in **the** morning.

Comment: The lack of an article for "man" is tricky.  Man used without an article refers to  mankind in general.  Without any further context, it's assumed that the intended meaning is this, but it could just as easily be "the" or "a".